# Webmatrix with pre-installed PHP

Tags: php, webmatrix, iis-express

I already have PHP 5.3.6 installed, is there a way to direct WebMatrix to make use of the installed PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebMatrix uses IIS Express webserver (IIS Express gets installed along with WebMatrix) and you need to configure IIS Express to use installed PHP. Run the following two commands from IIS Express installation folder (%programfiles%\IIS Express) and restart WebMatrix.

1. appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='c:{php_installation-folder}\php-cgi.exe']
2. appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='c:{php_installation-folder}\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Unspecified']

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, although WebMatrix says I'm using unknown version of PHP.

Comment: Two things I found though: PHP set %PHPRC% to my php installation directory which is handy, and path should be set to '\*.php' and verb '\*'. So between the two:    
    
`appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCGI /+[fullPath='^%PHPRC^%php-cgi.exe']`  
    
and    
    
`appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='^%PHPRC^%php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Unspecified']`